# How to disable the selected button in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 navbar's, a header and a footer. When I select a button on header, it highlighted. But when I select another button on footer, a new button on footer is also highlighted. How do I unselect the button on the header navbar when selecting this new button and vice versa?

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-id="mynavbar" id="myheader">
<>...buttons<>

<div data-role="navbar" data-id="mynavbar" id="myfooter">
<>... buttons<>
```

Comment: What jQuery Mobile version are you using? Because in version 1.2 if you click a button all other active buttons are deselected.

Comment: 1.2: other buttons must be on the same group. I actually have 2 navbar's